# ajuda para View passar várias linha para um Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera, tenho um modelo simples para estudos. São 3 tabelas, Pessoa, Alergia e PessoaAlergia. Sendo que uma pessoa pode ter várias alergias.

Meu modelo de pessoa é:

```
 public partial class Pessoa
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Pessoa()
        {
            this.AlergiasPessoas = new HashSet<AlergiasPessoas>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AlergiasPessoas> AlergiasPessoas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Em minha View Create recebo os dados da tabela alergia em uma listbox onde o usuário pode selecionar vários.

```
@Html.ListBox("Alergia", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Alergia, new { @id = "Fonte", @class = "form-control", @onclick = "teste(this)", @style = "height:150px" })
```

Ao enviar os dados para o Concroller por submit, espero gravar tanto a pessoa quanto as alergias selecionadas na tabela PessoaAlergia

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,nome")] Pessoa pessoa, ALGO_QUE_TRAGA_OS_ITENS_SELECIONADOS)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pessoa.Add(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var item in ALGO_QUE_TRAGA_OS_ITENS_SELECIONADOS)
            {
                AlergiasPessoas alergiasPessoas = new AlergiasPessoas();
                alergiasPessoas.ID_Pessoa = pessoa.ID;
                alergiasPessoas.ID_Alergia = item.ID;
                db.AlergiasPessoas.Add(alergiasPessoas);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pessoa);
    }
```

**Não estou sabendo como receber os itens selecionados na action create. Alguma sugestão?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AlamBique, o @Html.ListBox vai passar um array com os Ids selecionados na View.
Você pode pegar do jeito que estava fazendo mesmo usando um foreach. 
Mude seu metodo POST para...
`public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,nome")] Pessoa pessoa, int[] Alergia)`

Comment: Obrigado Daniel!

Comment: Então o que vale é o nome do item HTML para poder receber no controller? Tipo nesse exemplo a tag  gerada @Html.ListBox("Alergia". Para receber eu uso Alergia.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, uma das formas de fazer isso é utilizando uma ViewModel, que irá trafegar as informações para da controller para a view e retornar da View para a controller. Veja no link a seguir uma referencia sobre como esses componentes funcionam no detalhe e um exemplo: [Microsoft Docs: Views And ViewModels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

Sobre o seu caso, pode fazer o seguinte: 
 1- criar uma ViewModel contendo uma propriedade com a classe Pessoa.

2- Referenciar a ViewModel na view `@model ViewModelPessoa`

3- Utilizar a ViewModel para carregar os dados na view e submeter os dados por um formulário:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Pessoa.AlergiasPessoasSelecionada, m.AlergiasPossiveis, new { id = ListAlergiaPessoas })
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Isto AlamBique! E a solução apontada pelo @Alexandre é a mais elegante, se já estiver usando o conceito de View Model no seu projeto, pode usar a solução que ele apontou.  Eu pessoalmente gosto muito deste conceito.